# PowerQuery choose values based on a key column

Tags: powerquery, m

I have very large files which PowerQuery seems to handle nicely. I need to do some mathematical operations using column `d` and the value from columns `a`, `b` or `c` based on the value of the `key` column. My first thought is to isolate the salient value making a column called `Salient` which selects the value I need and then go from there. In Excel, this might be: `=INDEX($A:$E, ROW(F2), MATCH(A2,$A$1:$D$1))`.

[image: Highlighted PowerQuery Window]

In reality, I have between 50 and 100 columns as well as millions of rows, so extra points for computational efficiency.

Comment: Is this table just keys or are there other columns not shown in your image?

Comment: This is a toy example. There are about 50 columns whose header might appear in the keys column and 10 or 20 more columns whose header does not.

Comment: OK. My first thought involved unpivoting but might not be so great if you have data columns in addition to key columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom column `Salient` with just this as the definition:

```
Record.Field(_, [Key])
```

The M code for the whole step looks like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Prev Step Name", "Salient", each Record.Field(_, [Key]), Int64.Type)
```

The `_` represents the current row, which is a record data type that can be expressed as e.g.

```
[Key = "a", a = 17, b = 99, c = 21, d = 12]
```

and you use [Record.Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/record-field) to pick the field corresponding to the `Key`.

Comment: Brilliant! Such a powerful tool. I need to learn more.